# NodeJS request returns 403

Tags: node.js

I'm having an issue with the request module from npm for NodeJS where it refuses to communicate with a server with a self-signed certificate. When I run the following code:

```
const url = require('url');
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request-promise-native');

const rawRequest = (method, uri) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = url.parse(uri);
        options.method = method;
        options.rejectUnauthorized = false;

        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            let body = '';

            res.on('data', (data) => {
                body += data;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                resolve(body);
            })
        });

        req.on('error', reject);

        req.end();
    });
}

rawRequest('GET', 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/v1/')
.then((res) => {
    console.log('[rawRequest-SUCCESS]');
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('[rawRequest-ERROR]', error.message);
});

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/v1/',
    rejectUnauthorized: false
})
.then((res) => {
    console.log('[request-SUCCESS]');
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error('[request-ERROR]', error.message);
});
```

I get the results of:

```
[rawRequest-SUCCESS]
[request-ERROR] Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=403
```

I've tried dozens of different ways of configuring the request call, including using `agent` and `agentOptions` in various configurations including `strictSSL`, `rejectUnathorized`. I've even gone so far as to include `process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;` before the calls even start with no luck.

Why does the raw request work where the request library does not?

Comment: Can you try hitting the URL in code without the "S": `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/v1/` ?

Comment: Unfortunatley I cannot. It's an internal server that only operates on HTTPS (and on a non-standard port as well) due to security requirements.

Comment: There is no browser involved, this is a NodeJS script.

Comment: Same results. This isn't trying to get outside of the network, one method works, one method doesn't. From my understanding of the request module, it leverages the same underlying modules built into Node (http and https). The API loads just fine in my browser and in Postman as well, and even works when I request it using a Python script.